# Prove that $\frac AB \leq \frac{A+C}{B+D} \leq \frac CD$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

Assume $\frac{A}{B} \le \frac{C}{D}$     and $A,B,C,D   \in  \mathbb{R}^+$

Prove that $\frac{A}{B} \le \frac{A+C}{B+D} \le\frac{C}{D}$

(this is a homework exercise I have to do, so please help me :(

Comment: If this is a homework exercise you have to do, you should probably do it.

Comment: Yes, but i have no idea how to solve it

Comment: Please tell us what you tried, or what you think your first step should be.

Comment: I tried doing A(B + D)/B =< A + C =< C(B + D)/ D

Comment: But now I'm stuck at A + AD/B =< A+C =< CB/D + C

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should add your trials to the question (note that you can [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3921135/edit) it). That way, other MSE users will see your efforts to solve your homework and try to help, instead of voting negatively or closing the question.

Comment: BTW, check the conditions on $A,B,C,D$, because what you wrote is not true. $\frac{1}{-2}\le\frac{3}{4}$ but $\frac{1 + 3}{(-2) + 4} = 2 > \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: yes, A,B,C,D € R+ except 0, but my formatting got reported when I put that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, when you are asked to prove $m<n$ usually it is easier to start with working out $m-n$. Assuming that $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are positive:

$$\frac{A}{B}-\frac{A+C}{B+D}=\frac{AB+AD-AB-BC}{B(B+D)}=\frac{AD-BC}{B(B+D)} = \frac{-BD(\frac{C}{D}-\frac{A}{B})}{B(B+D)}\le0$$

$$\frac{C}{D}-\frac{A+C}{B+D}=\frac{BC+CD-AD-CD}{D(B+D)}=\frac{BC-AD}{D(B+D)}= \frac{BD(\frac{C}{D}-\frac{A}{B})}{B(B+D)}\ge 0$$